# How to classify services in microservices?

Tags: node.js, .net, .net-core, microservices

I am new in microservices. I am coming from monolithic background in current environment i have different kinds services for different purposes like search, file, email, notification. I have taken so many courses but in that the instructor separate each entity and make it's own database also create API for that(like separate shopping cart entity, product entity) it makes no sense, I am not getting what is real world use of microservices or how to make separate component to build it's own microservice.

Can anyone give Real Project example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://medium.com/@oyedejipeace/building-a-simple-microservices-app-with-express-gateway-a8fd49d81aeb) and [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics). Also look [here](https://github.com/IBM/nodejs-microservice) and [here](https://github.com/microservices). I don't think that anyone will give a link to the real working project, so you can try [this](https://github.com/mochow13/nodejs-microservices).

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting what is real world use of microservices

mostly as you heard in all of those tutorials the microservices architecture leverage advantages of:

- the smaller services are easy to maintain and develop
- easily can scale specific services rather than the whole project(monolith). for example you scale service-1 to 4 instances that request traffic split into these 4 instance and service-2 to 2 instances and go on (load balance). and these services may distributed in to different servers and locations.
- if one service failed to work it does not terminate the whole system since they are independent.
- services can be reusable for other scenarios or features.
- small team can works for each services and its easy to manage both project and development flow.

and also it suffer from disadvantages of

- services are simple and small but all as a whole system is complex so designing part are very critical.
- poor performance and it requires do some extras to improve the performance (different types of caching on different levels).
- transactions are complex and its developments are time costly. imagine simple update should be projected to other services if its required and you have to consider failure and rollback strategy ( SAGA ).

> how to make separate component to build it's own microservice

this is the most challenging part of microservices. you need deep study on Domain driven design DDD.

[Decompose by subdomain](https://microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-subdomain.html)

 [Decompose by Business Capabilities](https://microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-business-capability.html)

> Can anyone give Real Project example?

there are many projects the develop microservices with different patterns. I think you have to start your own and make your hands dirty.